# Confusing with the Models example in djangobook

Tags: python, django

I following the djangobook online chapter 5 http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/, there is a books model with Publisher, Author and Book. But it seems they missed to mention about how to add the data for the Book Model which contains complex relationship one-many and many-many with Publisher and Author, so I tried to do it by myself and got some problems.

Book model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

This is Publisher:

```
p = Publisher.objects.get(id=1)
```

This is Author:

```
a = Author.objects.get(id=1)
```

According to this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/, I decided to create the Book first and then add the author later:

```
b = Book(title='Django for dummy', publisher=p, datetime.datetime.now())
```

Error occurred: **SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg**

Could anyone point me the correct way ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, postional args must be put ahead of keyword args. Do `publication_date=datetime.datetime.now()` while passing the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Your call is of the form

```
b = foo(bar="test", "baz")
```

You can't do that.
Imagine that foo is defined like this

```
def foo(size, weight, bar):
...
```

When Python tries to call `foo` it can't. Because in my example, Python can't know what parameter to assign `"baz"` to. It's not `weight` because since you started using a keyword arg (`bar="test"` or anything with a keyword and value) now position means nothing. It could assign `"baz"` to `weight` because it's the second argument, but that would imply that `size` was the first argument, and you've explicitly stated that it isn't.

When you're constructing an object like this, basically just use keyword arguments.

You can fix this error in general by making all your arguments keyword, or all positional or putting the positional ones first. I'd do the first of these:

```
b = Book(title='Django for dummy', publisher=p, publication_date=datetime.datetime.now())
```